# Using IF Statements on Vectors in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

So I'm trying to code my fraud detection algorithm using R. I have a numerical value (fraudval) proportional to how likely it is that a certain user is committing fraud in a vector. How do I create a new column that would state if it's HIGH, MEDIUM, or LOW, given some sensitivity of 'fraudval' (i.e. if 0.6 > 'fraudval' > 0.3, then it's LOW, if in between 0.6 and 0.8 MED, and and HIGH if it's 0.8 or higher.

Here is my input and expected output

sensitivities are: very low - 0, low - 0.3, medium - 0.6, high - 0.8

**input (df)**:

```
ID fraudval
1  0.4
2  0.8
3  0.2
4  0.6
```

**output (df)**:

```
ID fraudval test
1  0.4      LOW
2  0.8      HIGH
3  0.2      VERY LOW
4  0.6      MEDIUM
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: `cut` and `ifelse` are probably your best options.  I'd take a look at `?cut` and see if you can finagle that into what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `cut`:

```
R> df$test <- cut(df$fraudval, c(0,.3,.6,.8,Inf),
+                c("VERY LOW", "LOW", "MED", "HIGH"), right=FALSE)
R> d
  ID fraudval     test
1  1      0.4      LOW
2  2      0.8     HIGH
3  3      0.2 VERY LOW
4  4      0.6      MED
```